# What is the scope of state tokens for delta queries in the Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have an application that runs on multiple independent devices that keeps track of messages in the same Outlook mail folder. I use a [message delta function call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for this. Each instance maintains its own delta link in a text file. This solution works great on a single device. However, when I run the application on a second device, I sometimes get a 'SyncStateNotFound' error on one of the devices because the delta link became invalid when another device synced a couple of times.

From [another stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51936487/11481869) I understand that the Graph API stores only the three most recent state tokens, but what is the scope of these tokens? Do the tokens belong to a resource (message folder) or is there also a kind of synchronization session? Should a different *Application Id* or *Authorization Code* give a different set of sync state tokens? Do I use the same sync tokens if I access the resource on behalf of a different user that has delegated access to the same mailbox? Or is there another simple solution to acquire a second set of tokens?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you share syncstate across devices? If so, this is not supported. Every device should have its own sync state token.

Regarding scope of the token, it belongs to the folder. You should avoid reusing of the tokens.

Comment: Each device keeps its own delta link and these are never shared across devices.